# Adding custom property to VertexGroup class

Tags: python, properties, vertex-groups

I am experiencing a problem with adding Custom properties to `bpy.types.VertexGroup`

I have added custom properties to various types before, Object, Material, etc.

```
>>> C.active_object.niftools_constraint
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].niftools_constraint
```

However looking at the one for the VertexGroup I get the following and am unable to see the defined properties of the Property group

```
>>> C.active_object.vertex_groups.active.niftools_skin_data
(<built-in function PointerProperty>, 
{'description': 'Additional vertex group properties used by the Nif File Format', 
'name': 'Niftools Vertex Group Property', 
'type': <class '__main__.VertexGroupProperty'>})
```

The sample code show a working custom Object property and the non-working VertexGroup property.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import (PointerProperty,

class ObjectCollision(PropertyGroup):
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        bpy.types.Object.niftools_constraint = PointerProperty(
                        name='Constraint Property',
                        description='Additional constraint properties used by the Nif File Format',
                        type = cls
                        )

        cls.LHMaxFriction = FloatProperty(
                        name='LHMaxFriction',
                        description='Havok limited hinge max friction.',
                        )
        cls.tau = FloatProperty(
                        name='tau',
                        description='Havok limited hinge max friction.',
                        )
        cls.damping = FloatProperty(
                        name='damping',
                        description='Havok limited hinge max friction.',
                        )

    @classmethod
    def unregister(cls):
        del bpy.types.Object.niftools_constraint

class VertexGroupProperty(PropertyGroup):
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        bpy.types.VertexGroup.niftools_skin_data = PointerProperty(
                        name='Niftools Vertex Group Property',
                        description='Additional vertex group properties used by the Nif File Format',
                        type = cls
                        )

        cls.blah = BoolProperty(
                        name=('bonedata'), 
                        description='None',
                        default = False
                        )

    @classmethod
    def unregister(cls):
        del bpy.types.VertexGroup.niftools_skin_data


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectCollision)

    bpy.utils.register_class(VertexGroupProperty)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectCollision)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VertexGroupProperty)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 4):

Quote from the [api documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.props.html#assigning-to-existing-classes):

> Custom properties can be added to any subclass of an ID, Bone and PoseBone.

`VertexGroup` does not inherit from [ID](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.ID.html#module-bpy.types).

Comment: Yes, been talking to ideasman42, missed this topic too - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/is-it-possible-to-add-a-custom-property-on-bpy-types-sequence