# Custom Properties in space_data or region3d

Tags: python

is it possible to create custom properties in context.space_data or context.space_data.region3d?

I created a property in bpy.types.SpaceView3D.my_prop but couldn't access it via bpy.context.space_data.my_prop.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1155/2271) for a listing of classes which support custom properties.

Neither [Space](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.Space.html) nor [RegionView3D](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html) derive from [ID](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.ID.html) and are not treated special and can not have custom properties.

[Screen](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.Screen.html) does inherit and might be a candidate. You might identify an area by its **index** or its **hash**.

The former should work with loading/saving the screen from/to the *.blend file. 
The latter might persist during changes to the screen layout at runtime.